# Java to VB.Net Conversion [Small Snippet]

Tags: java, vb.net, code-snippets, translate

I have this snippet, it's in Java:

```
final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
final NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
key = new String(ni.getHardwareAddress());
```

Example of key output:   ▲╔UiÎ

What is the equivalent in VB.Net? I understand the first line gets Local Host, what about the rest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leaving the conversion aside, creating a string from arbitrary bytes is a terrible idea - compounded by the fact that you're not specifying the character encoding to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This iterates over all local interfaces:

```
Dim theNetworkInterfaces() as System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

for each curInterface as System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface in theNetworkInterfaces

   MessageBox.Show(curInterface.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString())
```

The physical address is what you want.

The line

```
final NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
```

just grabs the specific network interface by the inetaddress 
Say you store your localhost address in a variable called localIa and then you can use it:

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localIa)
ni.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
```